# Get Content of all Bucket Objects

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have several data(csv) files in S3 bucket arranged in following virtual directory:

```
s3://mybucketname/data/Type1/
```

Bucket Name: mybucketname
Key Prefix: /data/Type1/

and I want to combine content of these csv files in this bucket+key 
and return the output as string. Code -

```
public string GetBucketContents(string bucketName)
{
    string bucketContent = "";
    ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest
    {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        Prefix = "data/Type1/"
    };

    using (ListObjectsResponse response = amazonS3Client.ListObjects(request))
    {
        //Loop all objects in S3 bucket
        foreach (S3Object s3Object in response.S3Objects)
        {
            //Get S3 object @ s3Object.Key
            GetObjectRequest objectRequest = new GetObjectRequest().WithBucketName(bucketName).WithKey(s3Object.Key);                   
            using (GetObjectResponse objectResponse = amazonS3Client.GetObject(objectRequest))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(objectResponse.ResponseStream))
                {
                    bucketContent += reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return bucketContent;
}
```

I am getting expected output :-)
But still want to verify if there is any better (performance-wise) way to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a newer version of .net that supports the aync and await ajaxy magic then you could fire all the read requests off at once and then await all of them returning to construct your string. On large data reads this can improve the performance and shave off a good chunk of time.

Here is some code: (you would need to modify the strings to suit your purpose and get rid of the stopwatch but have included so you can see the time difference)

```
public string GetBucketContents(string bucketname)

    string prefix = "S3/PathToCSVs/";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    List<Task<string>> tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    // Begin timing
    sw.Start();

    using (client = new AmazonS3Client(AWSAccessKey, AWSSecretKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest2))
    {
        try
        {
            ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest
            {
                BucketName = bucketname,
                Prefix = prefix
            };

            do
            {
                ListObjectsResponse response = client.ListObjects(request);


                // Process response.
                foreach (S3Object entry in response.S3Objects)
                {
                    GetObjectRequest gor = new GetObjectRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = bucketname,
                        Key = entry.Key
                    };


                    tasks.Add(Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        return ProcessResults(gor, sw);
                    }));

                }

                // If response is truncated, set the marker to get the next 
                // set of keys.
                if (response.IsTruncated)
                {
                    request.Marker = response.NextMarker;
                }
                else
                {
                    request = null;
                }
            } while (request != null);


            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

            foreach (var s in tasks)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(sw.Elapsed.ToString() + "<br/>");
                sb.AppendLine(s.Result + "<br/>");
            }


            // Stop timing
            sw.Stop();
            sb.AppendLine(sw.Elapsed.ToString() + "<br/>");

            return sb.ToString();

        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
        {
            if (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode != null && (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidAccessKeyId") || amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidSecurity")))
            {
                return "Check the provided AWS Credentials. To sign up for service, go to http://aws.amazon.com/s3";
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Format("Error occurred. Message:'{0}' when listing objects", amazonS3Exception.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static string ProcessResults(GetObjectRequest gor, Stopwatch sw)
{
    string result = "";

    using (GetObjectResponse goresp = client.GetObject(gor))
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(goresp.ResponseStream))
        {
            result = sw.Elapsed.ToString() + "<br/>" + reader.ReadToEnd() + "<br/>";
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am from developer team site of Bucket Explorer. Bucket Explorer's export to csv feature provides you a option to export the data related information to export in csv format.

http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--export-object-details-to-csv.html